# How can I call an external command from within Miller (mlr)’s DSL?

Tags: shell, csv, miller

Suppose I have the following CSV:

```
$ cat test.csv
id,domain
1,foo.com
2,bar.com
```

Using `mlr put`, I can easily map any function over a field in the CSV, as long as I can define it in the Miller [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). So, for example, `mlr --csv put '$id = $id + 1'` will increment the `id` by 1 for each record.

But what if I can’t define the function in Miller’s DSL, perhaps because it is not pure? Suppose I wanted to map each domain in the CSV to an IP address. I’d like to do something like `mlr --csv put '$ip = shell("nslookup $domain")`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Currently I am extracting the input field into a separate file, rewriting it in a separate shell script, and adding the result back in with `mlr join`. However, this is pretty messy, because my CSV is full of quoted commas and newlines, which I need to carefully handle myself rather than relying on Miller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Update:** [as of September 2019](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/commit/4f5dd867ef356997c2a26a9739c33a3fb0d381df#diff-2f858af1f8713c36707ce06bff752c8a), the [`system()` DSL function](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-dsl.html) can be used for this purpose.

## Calling external commands from the Miller DSL

The Miller DSL reference deals with calling external commands in the section on [redirected-output statements](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-dsl.html#Redirected-output_statements):

> The *print*, *dump*, *tee*, *emitf*, *emit*, and *emitp* keywords all allow you to redirect output to one or more files **or pipe-to commands**.

I couldn’t find this in the documentation (other than by inference from the examples), but the syntax for using these statements with a pipe-to command seems to be `{statement} | {quoted-shell-command}, {unquoted-mlr-expression}`. For example:

```
$ mlr --csv put 'tee | "tr [a-z] [A-Z]", $*' test.csv
id,domain
1,foo.com
2,bar.com
ID,DOMAIN
1,FOO.COM
2,BAR.COM
```

Note that the piped output appears after Miller’s output (in this case, the unchanged input, as `tee` does not affect the stream and `put` emits it). By suppressing `put`’s output with `-q`, and extracting a single field with `print $domain` rather than `tee $*`, we can get a list of IP addresses:

```
$ mlr --csv put -q 'print | "xargs dig +short", $domain' test.csv
23.23.86.44
104.27.138.186
104.27.139.186
```

Miller didn’t do much for us here; we still had to use `xargs` to convert stdin into an argument (because `dig` does not accept domains on stdin). Moreover, `dig`’s output contained newlines, meaning that the output no longer matches the input one-to-one. Since `mlr` adheres to the Unix philosophy, it would have been easier just to join a pipe to the end of `mlr --headerless-csv-output cut -f domain` if this was all I needed.

### Joining output from external commands to your input

What I really wanted to do was assign the result of calling an external command to an in-stream variable in the Miller DSL<del>, and as far as I can tell, this is not possible</del>. However, by swapping `xargs` for [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), we can use the `--tag` option to keep track of the argument we gave `dig`, and benefit from flexible, concurrent I/O:

```
$ mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output cut -f domain test.csv | parallel --tag dig +short
foo.com 23.23.86.44
bar.com 104.27.139.186
bar.com 104.27.138.186
```

Since we are dealing with CSV, `parallel` can actually handle this on its own, although we need to access fields by position (`{2}`) rather than name (`domain`):

```
$ < test.csv parallel -C "," --skip-first-line --tagstring {2} dig +short {2}
foo.com 23.23.86.44
bar.com 104.27.139.186
bar.com 104.27.138.186
```

This is a tab-separated list of `(domain, ip)` pairs, so we can convert it back to CSV with a header using `mlr --t2c --implicit-csv-header label domain,ip`. Then, since both our output and our original `test.csv` have a `domain` field, we can use `mlr join` to produce a single output table, and `mlr nest` to implode the multiple values for `bar.com`:

```
$ mlr --csv cut -f domain test.csv | \
  parallel --skip-first-line --tag dig +short | \
  mlr --t2c --implicit-csv-header label domain,ip | \
  mlr --c2p --barred join -f test.csv -j domain then \
  nest --implode --values --across-records -f ip
+---------+----+-------------------------------+
| domain  | id | ip                            |
+---------+----+-------------------------------+
| foo.com | 1  | 23.23.86.44                   |
| bar.com | 2  | 104.27.138.186;104.27.139.186 |
+---------+----+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Since this is a good answer, please flag this question as answered.